# VHDL BCD Adder code - ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - <unsigned> is not declared

Tags: vhdl

I am using the textbook titled Digital Systems Design using VHDL (2nd Edition) by Charles H. Roth and Lizy Kurian John. I have been following the VHDL code samples providing in the book but I have tried a segment that is producing errors.

The VHDL code sample is given below (it comes straight out of the textbook).

```
library ieee;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity BCD_Adder is
    Port (
        X : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
        Y : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
        Z : out unsigned(11 downto 0)
    );
end BCD_Adder;

architecture BCDadd of BCD_add is

alias Xdig1 : unsigned(3 downto 0) is X(7 downto 4);
alias Xdig0 : unsigned(3 downto 0) is X(3 downto 0);

alias Ydig1 : unsigned(3 downto 0) is Y(7 downto 4);
alias Ydig0 : unsigned(3 downto 0) is Y(3 downto 0);

alias Zdig2 : unsigned(3 downto 0) is Z(11 downto 8);
alias Zdig1 : unsigned(3 downto 0) is Z(7 downto 4);
alias Zdig0 : unsigned(3 downto 0) is Z(3 downto 0);

signal S0 : unsigned(4 downto 0);
signal S1 : unsigned(4 downto 0);
signal C : bit;

begin

S0 <= '0' & Xdig0 + Ydig0; --overloaded +
Zdig0 <= S0(3 downto 0) + 6 when (S0 > 9) else S0(3 downto 0); --add 6 if needed
C <= '1' when (S0 > 9) else '0';

S1 <= '0' & Xdig1 + Ydig1 + unsigned'(0=>C); --type conversion done on C before adding
Zdig1 <= S1(3 downto 0) + 6 when (S1 > 9) else S1(3 downto 0);

Zdig2 <= "0001" when (S1 > 9) else "0000";

end BCDadd;
```

I'm using ISE Project Navigator by Xilinx to simulate the VHDL code. When I run a syntax check on the VHDL code it produces the following error:-

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:374 - Line 14: Entity  is not yet compiled.
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - Line 16:  is not declared.
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - Line 17:  is not declared.
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - Line 19:  is not declared.
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - Line 20:  is not declared.
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - Line 22:  is not declared.
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - Line 23:  is not declared.
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - Line 24:  is not declared.
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - Line 26:  is not declared.
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - Line 27:  is not declared.

The error is referring to the lines that starts with ***alias***. I have googled around to see if I can find a solution to this error but I have had no luck. Some websites mentioned that ***alias*** is not supported by most synthesis tools.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to resolve this problem.

Thank you very much,

Lincoln

Answer (score 3):

The name of the primary unit in the architecture declaration doesn't match the entity simple name:

```
entity bcd_adder is
```

vs:

```
architecture bcdadd of bcd_add is
```

Convert that to:

```
architecture bcdadd of bcd_adder is
```

You also need to add

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
```

to your context clause to make std_ulogic visible for the implicit type conversions from the character literals.

Also change the type of `c` so you don't need another type conversion:

```
    signal c : std_ulogic;
```

You'll find in the assignment

```vhdl
S1 <= '0' & Xdig1 + Ydig1 + unsigned'(0=>C); --type conversion done on C before adding
```

the type of `C` (bit) is not of the base type of an element of unsigned (std_ulogic) specified by the qualified expression. In -2008 package numeric_std "+" also supports an operand that is an element of unsigned without using an aggregate to provide an array type.

Your code then analyzes, and without writing a testbench, elaborates and simulates  (Which tells us there's no internal connectivity issues with ranges).

Comment: I followed your advise and it solved all the problems. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Lincoln On stackoverflow, we express "thank you" with upvotes and accepted answer. If David Koontz's answer solve your issue, please accept it: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Also, welcome to StackOverflow ;)